# How to remove h1 tag from Drupal Garland theme in the header

Tags: 6, theming

I was shocked to see Bing Webmaster Tools notification that my site: http://www.articlesdirectoryindia.com using Garland theme has two H1 tags and that only one should be there for SEO reasons.

Actually the site name : "Free Articles Directory India" is wrapped within h1 on all pages in the header which I want remove.

I want to know if there is any standard & tested workaround for removing this h1 and replacing this with some div etc?

I tried to change h1 to div for 10 minutes but I could not do it. Even if I'm able to it'd be difficult to test of all browser versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($logo || $site_title) {
        print '<h1><a href="'. check_url($front_page) .'" title="'. $site_title .'">';
        if ($logo) {
          print '<img src="'. check_url($logo) .'" alt="'. $site_title .'" id="logo" />';
        }
        print $site_html .'</a></h1>';
      }
```

These are the lines 39-45 in Garland Themes page.tpl.php. 
This is probably the h1 tag you're talking about. If you want to change it to div it should look like this afterwards:

```
if ($logo || $site_title) {
        print '<div class="youclassname"><a href="'. check_url($front_page) .'" title="'. $site_title .'">';
        if ($logo) {
          print '<img src="'. check_url($logo) .'" alt="'. $site_title .'" id="logo" />';
        }
        print $site_html .'</a></div>';
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean with html/css code? The answer Volker gave is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @JurgenR yes but I need some tested css too to display the title similarly. I had already tried this before posting here. I'm not able to make the title display in the same way.

Comment: So you did apply all css-styles of the former H1 to your new div?

Comment: You could post your css of the h1 and the div to compare...